# search in json object for a node

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I have a large json object and when I want to search for specific node in the json object i get `nullpointerexception` because that null doesn't exist and my json is like this

```
"InternetGatewayDevice": {
  "DeviceSummary": {
    "_value": "InternetGatewayDevice:1.1[](Baseline:1, DeviceAssociation:1, Time:1, QoS:1, Bridging:1, IPPing:1, USBLAN:1, WiFiLAN:1, GponWAN:1), VoiceService:1.0[1](Endpoint:1, SIPEndpoint:1)",
    "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
    "_type": "xsd:string"
  },
  "DeviceInfo": {
    "SpecVersion": {
      "_value": "1.0",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "HardwareVersion": {
      "_value": "V1.0",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "SoftwareVersion": {
      "_value": "V1.1",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "ProvisioningCode": {
      "_value": "",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    }
  },
  "ManagementServer": {
    "ConnectionRequestURL": {
      "_value": "xxxxxx",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    },
    "ParameterKey": {
      "_value": "",
      "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
      "_type": "xsd:string"
    }
  },
  "WANDevice": {
    "1": {
      "WANConnectionDevice": {
        "10": {
          "WANPPPConnection": {
            "1": {
              "ExternalIPAddress": {
                "_value": "xxxxxx",
                "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
                "_type": "xsd:string"
              },
              "Username": {
                "_value": "xxxxxxxx",
                "_timestamp": "2014-12-01T09:07:09.943Z",
                "_type": "xsd:string"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and I search for this `LANDevice` and I use this code to search for the node::

```
JArray deviceJArray = JArray.Parse(jsonResult);
var strAuthModeBasic = deviceJArray[0]["InternetGatewayDevice"]["LANDevice"]["InternetGatewayDevice"]["LANDevice"]["1"]["WLANConfiguration"]["1"]["BeaconType"]["_value"].ToString();
```

and I want to handle this exception please.

Comment: Are you asking what to do when the data is missing, or are you always getting this exception even for json with the valid data?

Comment: when I miss the data.

Comment: Are aware of the `try...catch` keywords?

Comment: try catch is a bad coding pattern for something like this - it will mask errors.

Answer (score 1):

I would do this by serializing the json into a c# complex object, where you can have null checking. The  reason why you are getting the error is because you are assigning a value that doesn't exist to the variable.

This is Microsoft's example of serialization if it is from a service: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

or if you just want to serialize a json string that you already have, use javascriptserializer:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've used something simillar, but in JS.

I haven't tested it, mind you. Basically: walk through the object, and return null when you encounter a missing step. If you manage to get to you actual main object, return required value.

```
var path = "path.to.your.object"; // instead of array["path"]["to"]["your"]["object"]
var fieldName = "_value";
array.Get(path, fieldName);

public static string Get(this JArray a, string path, string fieldName){
    // isnullorempty path -> return null
    var steps = path.Split(".");
    JArray obj = a;
    for(var i = 0; i < steps.length; ++i){
        obj = obj[steps[i]];
        if(obj == null) return null;
    }
    return obj[fieldName];
}
```